# How to make PDF text selectable using Apache PDFBox?

Tags: java, apache, pdf, javafx, pdfbox

I am trying to make text selectable at PDF reading application made on JavaFX. I have PDF files that contain screenshots with text and OCR layer. So I need the text to be selectable like at regular viewer. I set up getting image from page and now trying to figure out how to highlight text.

I tried following:

```
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(currentPdf);
    Image convertedImage;
    try {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(is);
        List<PDPage> list = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        PDPage page = list.get(pageNum);
        List annotations = page.getAnnotations();
        PDAnnotationTextMarkup markup = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);
        markup.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(600, 600));
        markup.setQuadPoints(new float[]{100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 500, 200, 500});
        annotations.add(markup);
        page.setAnnotations(annotations);
        BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 128);
        convertedImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);
        document.close();
        imageView.setImage(convertedImage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

but that results in image without any highlights.

I also tried to find information at stack overflow or other resources, but haven't found anything.

Would appreciate some Java code sample which enables text highlighting with mouse.

Comment: Please upload the PDF.

Comment: Here is the sample http://bit.ly/1OWKAa1

Comment: The good thing that is that it does indeed have text. In PDFBox 2.0, there is the tool DrawPrintTextLocations.java, please try that one. Your question is unclear, do you want a viewer with text mark feature, or do you want to highlight stuff and then save the PDF?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Certainly a viewer with text mark feature:
'I need the text to be selectable like at regular viewer'.
At the code sample I am trying to make some working runtime text selection to wrap that later into mouse click event handler, which would pass coordinates of selected area to method which performs selection.

Thanks, will check it out.

Comment: Essentially you draw the PDF to a bitmap image (so losing all information which pixels are text and which are not) and display that image. Thus, you need to tell javafx where text is.

Comment: @Polyakoff have also a look at the ExtractTextByArea.java example, this would get you the text from a selected area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ICEpdf and did the following:

```
question.getSelectedBounds()
                .stream()
                .map(Shape::getBounds)
                .forEach(bounds -> {
                    SquareAnnotation squareAnnotation = (SquareAnnotation)
                            AnnotationFactory.buildAnnotation(
                                    pdfController.getPageTree().getLibrary(),
                                    Annotation.SUBTYPE_SQUARE,
                                    bounds);
                    squareAnnotation.setFillColor(true);
                    squareAnnotation.setFillColor(new Color(255, 250, 57, 120));
                    squareAnnotation.setRectangle(bounds);
                    squareAnnotation.setBBox(bounds);
                    squareAnnotation.resetAppearanceStream(null);
                    AbstractAnnotationComponent annotationComponent = AnnotationComponentFactory
                            .buildAnnotationComponent(squareAnnotation, pdfController.getDocumentViewController(),
                                    pageViewComponent, pdfController.getDocumentViewController().getDocumentViewModel());
                    pageViewComponent.addAnnotation(annotationComponent);
                });
```